# vulkan: multiple calls to vkCmdBindPipeline in primary CommandBuffer

Tags: vulkan

I'm practicing with the vulkan API, Yesterday I wasted almost the entire day in implementing secondary buffers for use different fragment shaders on different objects.
Big issue was an error "segmentation fault" in call to  vkCmdDrawIndexed(). For the moment this is a matt black box for me, I don't find a method to investigate the origin of the issue. Although the vulkan API has validation layers for debug, it is already complicate without these ones. I suspect that the error is in the code for the creation secondary CommandBuffers.
Leaving out these problems due to my not knowing, I accidentally found that the code works the same with only the primary commandbuffer and multiple calls to vkCmdBindPipeline():

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer(primaryCommandBuffer...);
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(...);

vkCmdBindPipeline(...pipeline_things_a);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(...);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(...);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(...);
vkCmdSetViewport(...);
vkCmdSetScissor(...);
draw_things_a(...) {... vkCmdDrawIndexed(...) ...}

vkCmdBindPipeline(...pipeline_things_b);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(...);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(...);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(...);
vkCmdSetViewport(...);
vkCmdSetScissor(...);
draw_things_b(...) {... vkCmdDrawIndexed(...) ...}

vkCmdEndRenderPass(primaryCommandBuffer);
vkEndCommandBuffer(primaryCommandBuffer);
```

I'm outside regular learning path, so my question can be an obvious error for the most, but I ask:

Is it an error the multiple call of vkCmdBindPipeline() in primary command buffer?

Comment: "*Although the vulkan API has validation layers for debug, it is already complicate without these ones.*" Using validation layers makes using the API *simpler*, not more complicated. It also makes debugging simpler because it tells you (most) of the bad things you're doing.

Comment: Aren't you using validation layers? There're just innocent little layers which input stuff when they think something's wrong. They don't interfere with anything and just quietly do the printing and need a single string to be passed into your instance initialiser. These problems are better handled by the validation layers as they're probably caused by wrong input in one of the millions of Vulkan structs.

Comment: Ok! I done: instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"; and apt install vulkan-validationlayers-dev. I admit it is almost mandatory for writing code.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not an error. You can do arbitrary calls for e.g. binding pipelines within a single command buffer. In general you can call all commands beginning with `vkCmd` arbitrarily in a single command buffer as much as you want.